# How to host botkit bot/app on ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, slack, botkit

Has anyone here hosted a botkit app on ec2 instance? If yes, could you tell me how? I see options to host it on glitch/heroku but i want to host it on ec2.